# Closest singular matrix (Frobenius norm)

Tags: optimization, svd, computer-vision

Reading "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision", I am struggling to understand a result made to approximate a matrix $F$ to the closest singular matrix $F'$ (which represents the $3\times3$ [Fundamental Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision))).

This Fundamental matrix $F'$ has to be singular (more concretely of rank $2$). However, due to noise the initial guess $F$ may be of rank $3$. Given this, the authors state that:

> Let $F = UDV^T$ be the SVD of $F$, where $D$
> is a diagonal matrix $D = \text{diag} (r, s, t)$ satisfying $r ≥ s ≥ t$. Then $F'= U\text{diag(r, s, 0)}V^T$
> minimizes the Frobenius norm of $F − F$

But I can't understand why just by setting the smaller singular value of $F$ to zero we reach the matrix $F'$ (subject to $\det(F')=0$) that minimizes $\Vert F - F' \Vert^2$. Besides, why the same singular vectors are needed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have quoted is not a "derivation" of the closest low-rank approximation to $F$.  Some proofs of the result described by the author are given on the wikipedia page for [the EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm)).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: My bad that's true, I am going to edit it (my english needs to improve). Regarding the link thanks for it. I am reading it now.

Comment: Glad to help. This theorem, while it has many applications, is not usually discussed in linear algebra courses.